# jq split string and map

Tags: json, jq

I got the following string that I would like to convert to a json array.

```
   2 email1@myDomain.com
   1 email2@myDomain.com
   3 email3@myDomain.com
```

This is the jq command:

```
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1] | map({email: ., free: 0, used: 0})'
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "email": "   2 email1@myDomain.com",
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0
  },
  {
    "email": "   1 email2@myDomain.com",
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0
  },
  {
    "email": "   3 email3@myDomain.com",
    "free": 0,
    "used": 0
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "email": "email1@myDomain.com",
    "free": 2,
    "used": 0
  },
  {
    "email": "email2@myDomain.com",
    "free": 1,
    "used": 0
  },
  {
    "email": "email3@myDomain.com",
    "free": 3,
    "used": 0
  }
]
```

Can someone help? I need to split the string on the white space, which I know is possible but I don’t know the exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1] | map({email: split(" ")[1], free: split(" ")[0], used: 0})'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always better to avoid "slurping" when possible, and it would be more efficient to split on spaces just once:

```
jq -R '
  [splits(" +")]
  | {email: .[1],
     free:  (.[0] | tonumber),
     used: 0 }
' input.txt
```